# How to flash a WPF Window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make an options window for my WPF application. The options window should always be in the foreground, flash when the user clicks into the min window and can't be unfocused. Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Do you have any code to show that demonstrates what is and isn't working?  This is a bit vague so far.

Comment: You’re looking for a modal window.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I am using Mahapps. The MetroWindow doesn’t get flashed as Dialog.